# How to show length validation error only if field is filled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have validation like:

```
validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 500 }
```

> - Description can't be blank
> - Description is too short (minimum is 5 characters)

But, I want to show length validation error only if field is not left blank.

**So, if user has not typed in the field, this error should show up:**

> - Description can't be blank

**And if user has inputted less than 5 character, this error should show up:**

> - Description is too short (minimum is 5 characters)

---

<sub>Though, I just started learning RoR, it seemed to be little tricky. And I felt it will be even for others. So put this in SO. Have a look at my answer.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Ah, like this: (My boss replied)

```
validates :description, presence: true
validates :description, length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 500 }, allow_blank: true
```

I just needed to separate the presence validation and length validation. First it will check for its presence and then check for its length.